# How would one replicate this variable extrusion?

Tags: modeling

I'd like to know, how to do this in blender.

https://twitter.com/Motionworks/status/1267376593619410945

[image]

Comment: Hello :). One obvious way is proportional editing (just hide the faces you don't want affected). What have you tried so far?

Comment: well ive tried proportional editing but i douno how to make it slide the adjacent edges up like that to make the lip could you perhaps show me an example?

Comment: Please add some images of the exact part that's causing you trouble :). This is basically proportional extrusion with bevel modifier on the edges.

Comment: Yup.. Alt-S works with prop. editing